# Using iCarousel framework on storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, icarousel

Has anyone tried to implement [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) with storyboards? I have an existing project, but not sure if this will work with Storyboards or not. Has anyone done this successfully or provide any directions on what do I need to implement this in a Storyboard project?

Comment: @NickLockwood He is the creator of that he can probably answer that question the best.

Answer (score 6):

I've got to admit, I can't work out why Storyboards are causing an issue for so many people using iCarousel, but I've now included a Storyboard example in the project that demonstrates how to set it up correctly.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/tree/master/Examples/Storyboard%20Demo

FWIW, the view controller code for this example is identical to the Basic iOS demo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works with storyboards.
It works exactly the same way as before iOS 5 Storyboards.

You can create a view in your storyboard and set its class property to be "iCarousel".

Then connect iCarousel delegate and dataSource properties to point to your view controller. (don't forget that your view controller must implement iCarouselDataSource and iCarouselDelegate protocols). You can create an outlet for your iCarousel view too.

Thats all for you to access and to control your iCarousel using Storyboards.

Hope it helps,
hbobenicio.

Comment: Could you elaborate on delegate and dataSource pointing and implementing of the protocols? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that iCarousel.m is in the compile sources list for your app target. Project > App Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources in xCode 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

So, another problem is, that if a view-class was changed to iCarousel and command-b is set, after compiling the alert "Unknown class iCarousel in Interface Builder file." comes.

No, no, iCarousel and Storyboard isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Don't copy the class `iCarousel` in the project-folder by adding them.
Just reference to them. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

And the solution:
Make a new Class in your Xcode-Project, name it "iCarousel". Via drag & drop put the Code from the original classfiles in there.

After that, it will work'S well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having some issues but I just hadn't set the iCarousel.m file's Target Membership to the right thing when I dragged it in.

Answer (score -1):

That is wrong.

I've try to implement iCarousell in a Storyboard-Project and always get delegate and datasource errors. I think it only works with separated xib.

Always: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dataSource.'

Comment: I don't know the specific reason for your bugs, but I developed a project and we actually used iCarousell views instanciated by the storyboard.